# Searching for evidence-based published study that compares disinfectant residues after evaporation

Tags: reference-request, evaporation

I've been plowing through databases to find evidence-based research reporting on the residue remaining after evaporation of chemical disinfectants. I want to know if there is a study which states the amount of residue that disinfectants (which are commonly used for healthcare surfaces or cleanrooms) leave after evaporation in air-dry way (not via Residue on Evaporation RoE Test which includes heating the substance). These disinfectants are mostly common and include alcohol, chlorine and chlorine compounds, formaldehyde, glutaraldehyde (GTA), hydrogen peroxide (H2O2), iodophors, ortho-phthalaldehyde (OPA), peracetic acid, peracetic acid and hydrogen peroxide, phenolics, and quaternary ammonium compounds (quats).

I've found an article which states the amount of residue on some materials in healthcare equipment, but it doesn't say if the disinfectant has evaporated or not<sup>1</sup> . There are some reports from ALS lab too, but the source is not clear enough(*see image below*) <sup>2</sup> .

1. C. Lerones, A. Mariscal, M. Carnero, A. García-Rodríguez, J. Fernández-Crehuet, Assessing the residual antibacterial activity of clinical materials disinfected with glutaraldehyde, o-phthalaldehyde, hydrogen peroxide or 2-bromo-2-nitro-1,3-propanediol by means of a bacterial toxicity assay,.*Clinical Microbiology and Infection* **2004,** *10*, 984–989. [DOI: 10.1080/00397918908050700.](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1469-0691.2004.00967.x)
2. https://www.contecinc.com/articles/disinfectant-residues-mitigation-and-management/

[image]

Thanks community!

Comment: You are asking for references to reputable studies on disinfectant residues. The link you provided cites the following (which is the end of that road, it provides a citation at the end, which you consider "grey"): https://www.cleanroomtechnology.com/news/article_page/Challenging_disinfectant_residues_as_per_GMP_Annex_1/160751 In other words, it seems you want to compare the amount of residue left by different disinfectants. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes @BuckThorn ! The reason I said the citation is grey is because it's not a published study in acceptable journals. The image I used in my post is not from the link you have put in your comment. It's from ALS Lab (anecdotally) which you cannot find its source. Please also let me know what details should I provide for my question to get it reopened.

Comment: @BuckThorn 
I want to see if there is actually an evidence-based published study that compares disinfectants residues.

Comment: I would edit the title then to mention "evidence-based published study that compares disinfectants residues" and put the "reference-request" tag under the question. Also, I would remove the discussion of biofilms, which imo doesn't make sense. The residues are relevant in the context of the operation of *clean rooms* which have to maintain very high standards with regard to residues on surfaces or the air. That's what the company you linked to is concerned with.

Comment: @BuckThorn I changed the question to what you have desired. Hope it's now admissible for the community.

Comment: I took the liberty of modifying the title and editing parts of the grammar. Btw in hindsight maybe the biofilms question makes sense, but it is unnecessary to mention, so good to remove it.